# Is starting an std::thread in a class constructor thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

So I have a code something like this (C++11):

```
class Foo
{
    private:
        std::vector<int> vec;
        int val;
        std::thread Foo_thread;
    public:
        Foo();
        void StartLoop();
        void WaitTermination() { this->Foo_thread.join(); }
        void AddToVec(int dummy) { vec.push_back(dummy); }
        void setter(int val) { this->val = val; }
};

void Foo::StartLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // some code . . .
        this->vec.push_back(something);
    }
}

Foo::Foo()
{
    this->Foo_thread = std::thread(&Foo:SartLoop, this);
}

int main()
{
    Foo* f = new Foo{};
    f->WaitTermination();
}
```

If I understand well, the f pointer and the Foo instance lives in the main thread. In the constructor, `this->Foo_thread = std::thread(&Foo:SartLoop, this);`, the address of the Foo instance is passed to the std::thread, so this thread can access this object's members, for example in Foo::StartLoop(): this->vec.push_back.

However, the Foo class have a public AddToVec(), so in the main() I could write:

```
int main()
{
    Foo* f = new Foo{};
    f->AddToVec(78); // at this point, we modify the private vec member, both from the main thread and in the std::thread, if I undersand well
    f->setter(67); // same problem, however it's easier to declare val as std::atomic<int>, but the above one is really problematic
    f->WaitTermination();
}
```

My question is, do I understand well? How can I fix this code? I'd like to keep the constructor-creates-thread mechanism.

Thank you

Comment: Essentially, if multiple threads modify the data, you need to use synchronization primitives like `std::mutex`

Comment: In the main(), if I don't do the f->AddToVec(78);  f->setter(67); calls, my code is okey?

Comment: Well, you misspelled 'SartLoop', for one thing:(

Comment: Multithreading is hard. You need to read books like **C++ Concurrency in Action** or do some course to at least understand the basic principle. Otherwise, you will either get corrupted data or deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

It causes data race to call f->AddToVec(78); f->setter(67); in main. Without them, accessing the object under construction with `this` pointer is safe, in the sense that it's not UB and the language standard doesn't prohibit that.
But in practice, use of `this` under construction is not recommended and experienced developers often try to avoid because it leads to problems as code evolves:

- if the class happens to be polymorphic, calling virtual function
  before constructor finishes causes UB when a part of base classes are not fully initialized
- before the completion of constructor, the class invariants are not satisfied